# Same CakePHP controller with different "order by"

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have simple CakePHP controller, with index method.

My wish is to use same controller and same method, for two cases, where in one it will select (list) records from first category, in second from second category. So it looks very simple.

But in those two cases, I need different "Order By" MySQL statement.

Do I need to rewrite pagination methods, or there is another way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:** This is how selection of the records is made:

```
$contents = $this->Content->find('all', array('fields'=>array('Content.*'), 'order'=>array('Content.id DESC'), 'conditions' => array('Content.category_id' => $category_id)));
```

Usually, I will make pagination with

```
$data = $this->paginate('Content');
```

But in this case it is not enough, because I need (at least) two different "Order By" statements

Answer (score 0):

Just set `$this->paginate['Model']['order']` inbetween calls to `$this->paginate('Model');`. If this is not clear, update your answer with some code.

```
$this->paginate['Content'] = array('fields'=>array('Content.*'), 'order'=>array('Content.id DESC'), 'conditions' => array('Content.category_id' => $category_id)));
$contents = $this->paginate('Content');
```

Bare in mind you will have issues [paginating 2 models on the same page](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Paginate-Multiple-Models-in-the-same-view-td3261396.html).

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you `pr($this->paginate)` it will be clear that it is just a variable that you can change at your will